# How can I order a HashMap by an Integer key?

Tags: java, hashmap

This is my first question in StackOverflow, I'll be really happy if you could answer it to me: How can I order a HashMap by an Integer key?

Thanks, this is for a project I have to do for the university

Comment: This can be easily done. What you have tried so far ?

Comment: HashMap are not intended to be sorted and/or ordered. You need TreeMap.